# Hackerrank SQL challenge: Occupations

Tags: mysql

Pivot the Occupation column in OCCUPATIONS so that each Name is sorted alphabetically and displayed underneath its corresponding Occupation. The output column headers should be Doctor, Professor, Singer, and Actor, respectively.

Note: Print NULL when there are no more names corresponding to an occupation.

Input Format

The OCCUPATIONS table is described as follows:

Occupation will only contain one of the following values: Doctor, Professor, Singer or Actor.

Sample Input

Sample Output

Jenny    Ashley     Meera  Jane
Samantha Christeen  Priya  Julia
NULL     Ketty      NULL   Maria
Explanation

The first column is an alphabetically ordered list of Doctor names.
The second column is an alphabetically ordered list of Professor names.
The third column is an alphabetically ordered list of Singer names.
The fourth column is an alphabetically ordered list of Actor names.
The empty cell data for columns with less than the maximum number of names per occupation (in this case, the Professor and Actor columns) are filled with NULL values.

After searching and learning from internet, the correct answer for this challenge by using MYSQL:

---

```
SELECT MIN(IF(Occupation = 'Doctor',Name,NULL)),MIN(IF(Occupation = 'Professor',Name,NULL)),MIN(IF(Occupation = 'Singer',Name,NULL)),MIN(IF(Occupation = 'Actor',Name,NULL)) 
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Occupation
                             ORDER BY Name) AS row_num,
            Name, 
            Occupation
    FROM OCCUPATIONS) AS ord
GROUP BY row_num
```

---

My question is what does the function MIN doing in this code. also, the answer still correct after changing MIN to MAX but if i delete min or max, the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solution by MS SQL Server

```
Select Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor from (
 SELECT  name, 
               occupation,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation ORDER BY name) AS row_number
      FROM OCCUPATIONS
)dt
PIVOT (
    MAX(name)
    FOR [Occupation] IN ([Doctor],  [Professor],
                       [Singer],  [Actor])
)pt
ORDER BY row_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tried in another format but still similar code, but why it doesn't work?

```
select 
min(if(Occupation = 'Doctor', Name, NULL)),
min(if(Occupation = 'Professor', Name, NULL)),
min(if(Occupation = 'Singer', Name, NULL)),
min(if(Occupation = 'Actor', Name, NULL))
```

from(
select row_number() OVER(partition by Occupation
order by Name) as pr,
Name,
Occupation
from OCCUPATIONS) as row
group by pr